# What makes the probability distribution of a wavefunction in QM intrinsic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, probability, born-rule

I know that the usual interpretation of the wavefunction in QM is that it´s associated with a probability distribution of measurable quantities. Not a deterministic probability (like the probabilities connected with the throwing of a dice), but an intrinsic one. What makes the probability intrinsic?

Comment: The usual adjective is "intrinsic", not "inherent", right?

Comment: Right, left, right!

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are asking. The wave function itself doesn't have a probability interpretation. It can be used as input of a measurement process to produce a probability for the outcomes of the measurement process, but those probabilities belong to the process, not the wave function.

Comment: Why are those processes probabilistic?

Comment: Because they are open and we (have to) lose information about the system.

Comment: But that´s also the case if the probability came from an underlying mechanism (hidden variables), like the motion of the Brown particle that seemed completely random until the until the `hidden variables` in the form of the atoms or molecules in the surrounding liquid were discovered. I think it´s a matter of taste wich interpretation of the squared amplitude of the wavefunction you want to use. My choice is that the probability has un underlying mechanism because I can´t imagine that probability exists `an sich`. And like it´s written below by anna v both views are postulates.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that the usual interpretation of the wavefunction in QM is that it´s a probability distribution of measurable quantities.

It is a [postulate](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) that is necessary to choose the subset of mathematical sets that can be useful to modeling nature. The postulate was chosen because observations were fitted by the hypothesis.

> Not a deterministic probability (like the probabilities connected with the throwing of a dice),

Probabilities are probabilities. They may be defined by an underlying deterministic system, as with the dice

> but an inherent one. What makes the probability inherent?

It is inherent because it is a distribution that comes from the solution of an equation where the label "probability" has been given to the complex conjugate square of the wavefunction, by fiat, not studying underlying deterministic equations for their statistical distributions. The equation its self gives the distributions.

Comment: How can probability exist without un underlying mechanism?

Comment: That is why a postulate is needed. Postulates are like the axioms of mathematics, they have to be obeyed. It is a well validated theory and any attempt to create an underlying deterministic level either gives identical results, like Bohm's theory in the non relativistic case ,  or fails in lorenz invariance or somewhere else.

Comment: @descheleschilder - it may exist and it does exist. In classical physics, the fundamental description in principle allowed the uncertainties and error margins to be completely eliminated, so the probabilities between 0% and 100% only occurred due to incomplete knowledge that could be replaced by a complete one. In quantum mechanics, it's different. The uncertainty principle says that some minimum amounts of ignorance, e.g. the uncertainty of P and X, cannot ever be avoided, and correspondingly, the probabilities  between 0% and 100% are the most accurate things that the laws of physics predict

Answer (score 0):

There are explanations for why the probability of a measurement of a particular observable is the square amplitude of the relevant eigenstates.

The square amplitude is the only quantity that fits the calculus or of probability, and the rules of decision theory, and quantum physics:

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906015

http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2718.

The Born rule also follows from explanations about what information can be copied between two systems, see

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405161.